# Kubernetes Scaling Pods by reading json file which has a device count number

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, hpa

I have deployed all pods in Kubernetes environment with helm package system.
All my pods are running fine and I want to scale couple of pods based on the number of devices connected.

I'm maintaining a json file which has the count of devices connected for examply 1-5000, 5001-10000,etc.

Now I want my pods to scale up when the count reaches 5000, it shoulf create a replica of pod and the pod should scale up again if count reached 10000, and so on and scale down accordingly based on count value in json file.

Could anyone please let me know how can i scale my pods by above method ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where is the JSON file?  What configures it?  You could set your Helm chart to set the Deployment's `replicas:` if the JSON file is something that's available to the human running `helm` commands.

Comment: You can use hpa parameter in your k8 template, based on cpu or memory the replicas will be created. can you provide the code in which you want this change

Comment: @DavidMaze I can place my JSON file in any of the Linux volume mount path and it will get updated with count. Once count reaches 5000, the POD should create a replica. In the Deployment values.yaml, i have defined the replicas based on cpuutilizationpercentage but here , the replica should create based on the condition that count reached more than 1-5000(replica1), 5001-10000(replica2), and so on in my JSON

Comment: The contents of files in volumes aren't visible to anything in the Kubernetes API anywhere.  Unless you have something that can publish this value to an external metric system I'm not clear how you might connect it to any sort of autoscaler, short of complex options like writing your own Kubernetes controller to do it.  If it was a Helm value it would be relatively straightforward.